# jsreport "Error occured during reporter init "

Tags: jsreport

I'm just setting up jsreport over node.js following the installation instructions as stated [here](https://jsreport.net/on-prem). Everything goes fine until the last step:

```
jsreport start
```

Where the following error occurs:

```
2018-05-16T20:56:19.374Z - info: Initializing jsreport@2.0.0 in development mode using configuration file: jsreport.config.json
2018-05-16T20:56:19.378Z - info: Searching for available extensions in C:\Users\Mauro\
2018-05-16T20:56:19.382Z - info: Extensions location cache not found, crawling directories
2018-05-16T20:56:19.395Z - error: Error occured during reporter init TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at Object.exports.walkSync (C:\Users\Mauro\node_modules\jsreport-core\lib\util\util.js:46:10)
    at Object.get (C:\Users\Mauro\node_modules\jsreport-core\lib\extensions\locationCache.js:22:22)
    at <anonymous>
Error: An error has occurred when trying to initialize jsreport..
    at instance.init.then.catch (C:\Users\Mauro\node_modules\jsreport-cli\lib\instanceHandler.js:31:29)
    at <anonymous> {"originalError":{}}
(Original) TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at Object.exports.walkSync (C:\Users\Mauro\node_modules\jsreport-core\lib\util\util.js:46:10)
    at Object.get (C:\Users\Mauro\node_modules\jsreport-core\lib\extensions\locationCache.js:22:22)
    at <anonymous> {}
```

I'm attempting the installation on Windows 10. Any workaround would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please install jsreport into a dedicated directory.
Like `c:\work\myapp`.
Installing jsreport into your users' home causes some permissions issues currently.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, you can modify the `...\node_modules\jsreport-core\lib\util.js` file like this to get the `jsreport start` command to work:

[image]